# Why do they use "dp square" unit for measurements of baseline grid in relation to "icons", but "dp" unit in relation to "type"?

Tags: grids, mobile, dpi, typesetting, google-material-design

In this [specification document for Material Design in Android](http://www.google.com/design/spec/layout/metrics-keylines.html#metrics-keylines-keylines-spacing), it is written,

> All components align to an **8dp square** baseline grid. Type aligns
>   to a **4dp** baseline grid. Iconography in toolbars align to a **4dp
>   square** baseline grid.

Why have they used the **dp *square*** unit for the baseline grid for *UI components* and *iconography*, but the **dp** unit for the *type*?

Comment: because type doesnt fit into a grid? Type flows and lines break which cannot really defined by a square.

Comment: Type size is by default measured *vertically* - the *font size*. While modern software allows horizontal scale independently, it is highly preferred to not do that because it distorts characters. Thus, the width of text is supposed to scale along with its height. And since no two characters may have the same width (for a non-monospaced font at least), specifying a design by its width in 'font units' is hardly ever a requirement.

Comment: @Jongware Thank you so very much. If one of you can write it as an answer I can accept it. This will remove the question from the _to-be-answer_ queue and will be more helpful for future visitors.

Comment: @KMSTR Thank you so very much. If one of you can write it as an answer I can accept it. This will remove the question from the to-be-answer queue and will be more helpful for future visitors.

Answer (score 1):

Type flows and lines break which cannot really defined by a square, so **type doesn't really fit into a grid**. But take a look at baseline grid handling in Material Design:

[image]

from http://www.google.com/design/spec/style/typography.html#typography-line-height